# How to auto refresh in-memory cache in python?

Tags: python, caching

I have a requirement in python where I need to pull in data from an S3 bucket and save it in an in memory cache.

My requirement is that this cache should auto refresh itself every hour and pull in data from S3.

But, while the cache is getting refreshed (the data is large. Might take a few seconds), the user should be served from the old cache data. Basically, a user should not be waiting for the app to pull the record and keep waiting.

Is there a way (library or in built python tool) to achieve this?